# How do you define a customisable RGB background colour in java?

Tags: java, colors, background, jframe

I am new to java and I have searched for an answer on Google for a while now, but I cannot find a way to get an RGB background colour, I can only find how to set a background colour from the main colours already provided by java(for example, "Color.BLACK"). I am using a JFrame. Please help. Thanks. In this is my background code.

```
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        super.paintComponent(g);

        this.setBackground(Color.PINK); //My current background colour code but I am looking to use a customisable RGB one.

        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g.fillRect(0, 0, 40, y);

        tm.start();
    }
```

Comment: Context would help a lot here. Please show your current pertinent [mcve] code and tell the details of your code, your problem and your question.

Comment: Did you consider having a look at the [JavaDocs for `Color`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Color.html)?  Also, don't call `setBackground` and don't start your `Timer` in `paintComponent`, this can set up a never ending cycle of painting which can consume your CPU cycles.  Painting should paint the current state, it should never influence it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The context is missing, if you mean background color in Swing component (e.g JFrame, JPanel) they have methods getBackground() or setBackground(Color).

```
JPanel panel = new JPanel();
Color yourColor = panel.getBackground();
```

[Color](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Color.html) in java have lot of methods for return Color type eg.

```
int rgbValue = yourColor.getRGB(); // Returns the RGB value representing the color in the default sRGB ColorModel.
// or specific red, green, blue color value
int red = yourColor.getRed();
int green = yourColor.getGreen();
int blue = yourColor.getBlue();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can change

```
    this.setBackground(Color.PINK);
```

to

```
    this.setBackground(new Color());//Put RGB number in the empty parenthesis
```

Comment: -facepalm- I cannot believe I didn't realise this.